# how to match Some with any value in mockito

Tags: scala, mockito

My function under test returns `None` or `Some(ObjectOfSignupEmail)`. In my test case, I want to match that the returned value is `Some(ArgumentMatchers.any[SignupEmail])` but I get error

```
Expected :Some(null)
Actual   :Some(SignupEmail(Welcome,Test<mailrobot@test.com>,<a href=https://localhost:9000/test/ws/users/signup/11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111>Click here to verify email</a>))
```

If I change the code to `signupEmailOption mustBe Some(expectedAnswer)` where `expectedAnswer` is an instance of `SignupEmail` then the test passes.

Why `ArgumentMatchers.any` didn't work inside `Some`?

This doesn't work

```
"createEmailMessageForUserToken for all correct parameters" should {
    "return Some(email)" in {

      val mailConfig = Map("signupUrl"-> "/test/ws/users/signup/",
        "signupFrom"->"Test<mailrobot@test.com>",
        "signupReply"->"Test<noreply@test.com>",
        "signupSubject"->"Welcome")
      val mailerConfig = Map(
        "host" -> "localhost", // (mandatory). The domain of mail server i.e. the server is responsible for sending/receiving emails for this domain
        "port" -> "9000",
        "tlsRequired" -> "yes"
      )
      val newConfig = Map("mail"->mailConfig,
        "play.mailer"->mailerConfig)
      val newConfiguration = Configuration.from(newConfig)
      val testEnv = new TestEnv(newConfiguration)

      val signupEmailOption:Option[SignupEmail] = testEnv.controller.createEmailMessageForUserToken(testEnv.userToken)

       signupEmailOption mustBe Some(ArgumentMatchers.any(SignupEmail.getClass()))
    }


  }
```

This works

```
 "createEmailMessageForUserToken for all correct parameters" should {
    "return Some(email)" in {

      val mailConfig = Map("signupUrl"-> "/test/ws/users/signup/",
        "signupFrom"->"Test<mailrobot@test.com>",
        "signupReply"->"Test<noreply@test.com>",
        "signupSubject"->"Welcome")
      val mailerConfig = Map(
        "host" -> "localhost", // (mandatory). The domain of mail server i.e. the server is responsible for sending/receiving emails for this domain
        "port" -> "9000",
        "tlsRequired" -> "yes"
      )
      val newConfig = Map("mail"->mailConfig,
        "play.mailer"->mailerConfig)
      val newConfiguration = Configuration.from(newConfig)
      val testEnv = new TestEnv(newConfiguration)

      val url = "https://" + mailerConfig("host") + ":" + mailerConfig("port") + mailConfig("signupUrl") + testEnv.userToken.tokenId
      val html =s"<a href=${url}>Click here to verify email</a>"
      //println("html is "+html)
      val expectedAnswer = SignupEmail(mailConfig("signupSubject"),mailConfig("signupFrom"),html)
      println("expected answer would be "+expectedAnswer)

      val signupEmailOption:Option[SignupEmail] = testEnv.controller.createEmailMessageForUserToken(testEnv.userToken)
      signupEmailOption mustBe Some(expectedAnswer)

 //          signupEmailOption mustBe Some(ArgumentMatchers.any(SignupEmail.getClass()))
    }


  }
```

Comment: Try this: `Some(ArgumentMatchers.any(SignupEmail.getClass))`

Comment: didn't work. I suppose `any[SignupEmail]` is same as the option you proposed.

Comment: Can you paste the whole code?

Comment: updated the question

Comment: Thanks, is `mustBe` a method from mockito?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few options.

```
signupEmailOption should not be None

signupEmailOption should not be empty

signupEmailOption shouldBe defined

signupEmailOption should matchPattern { case Some(_) => }

inside(signupEmailOption) { case Some(_) => }
```

These are all equivalent.

But what you are doing - `signupEmailOption shouldBe Some(expectedAnswer)` is actually the best option of all. It is *the right* thing to do here. Just keep it like that.

*Note*: `should*` and `must*` assertions are pretty much the same thing, they just depend on which DSL trait you mix in.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `Scalatest` matchers instead of `Mockito` matchers for what you want to do

You are mixing concepts, mockito matchers are meant to be used in arguments of stubbed mock methods, if you want to assert the result of an invocation to your test object you have to use the matchers provided by your test framework (Scalatest in your case for what I can see), so basically check [this](http://doc.scalatest.org/3.0.0/index.html#org.scalatest.MustMatchers) page for the docs of `mustBe` and `Options`.

**A hint**: if you want to check the type of whatever is inside the `option`, you can use a partial function matcher and write something like

```
signupEmailOption should matchPattern { case Some(_: SignupEmail) => }
```